# Theorem Proving

Tags: boolean-computation, proof

It's a hard for me to write english so I'll try to go straight to my problem.
There is abstract predicate `f`, that takes two parameters. There are also two other predicates `b` and `u`:

```
b[x_, y_] := Exists[c, f[c, x] && f[c, y]]
u[x_, y_] := Exists[c, b[x, c] && f[c, y]]
```

Now I want *Mathematica* to prove next theorem:

```
Implies[ForAll[x, f[g, x]], ForAll[x, u[g, x]]]
```

Where `g` is abstract constant. Is it possible?

Comment: I would think you'd want to use the conditional version of `ForAll` like `ForAll[x,f[g,x],u[g,x]]` rather than `Implies`. Then to test the assertion, hit it with `Resolve` or `FullSimplify`.

Comment: @IPoiler, both `Implies[ForAll[x, f[g, x]], ForAll[x, u[g, x]]]` and `ForAll[x,f[g,x],u[g,x]]` do nothing, even when I try to apply `Resolve` or `FullSimplify` to them

Comment: Can anyone help me or at least tell that *Mathematica* is not capable of solving problems like that?

Comment: Looking at the documentation of `Resolve`, there appears to be support to work with functions like your `f`. Another simpler example that does not work: `Resolve[Implies[ForAll[c, c \[Element] Integers, f[c] \[Element] Integers], f[1] \[Element] Integers]]`

Comment: So is it a bug than? Should I add a "bugs" tag to my question or repot to Wolfram Support?

Comment: @rattrapper in general, it is not a bug if *Mathematica* cannot produce an answer. Of course, you can still approach Wolfram support and request support for problems like yours to be improved in the future.